# tests with connected components and redux #1262

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, formik

I'm trying to run tests with component connected to redux and formik. I've been testing several ways to get the result of getting submitted and checking in the state if there was indeed the addition, but all attempts were invalid ... Could anyone give me a try on redux test?

projetct: [https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test/blob/master/src/pages/**tests**/formDocumentos.test.js](https://github.com/henriqueweiand/reactjs-crud-state-test/blob/master/src/pages/__tests__/formDocumentos.test.js)

Answer (score 0):

If the component use `connect` you should wrap the component in a test with `Provider` to allow the component to use store values.